# How to only show specific values in Form with ModelChoiceField based on group/permissions?

Tags: django

This is what my UserCreateFrom looks like:

```
class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False)
    driver_number = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False)
    group = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Group.objects.all, required=True)
```

In my auth_group table I added a field for a role number. Like admin=1, editor = 2... If a user now accesses a site to create a user, I want him only to be able to choose a group for that new user, that has a higher value than his own group. So the admin can create everything, but the editor cant create an admin and so on. Is there a way to pass a value to the UserCreateForm which I then can use in the definition of the form field? Smth like this:

```
group = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Group.objects.filter(role>requesting_user_role), required=True)
```

My other idea would be to work with custom permissions, but I still would need to pass the user somehow when creating the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is to override the forms `__init__` method and accept a keyword argument there (would be either the requests user or his group).

```
class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False)
    driver_number = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False)
    group = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Group.objects.all, required=True)
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        requesting_user_role = kwargs.pop('requesting_user_role')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['group'].queryset = Group.objects.filter(role__gt=requesting_user_role)
```

In your view simply pass a parameter to the form with the users role:

```
UserCreateForm(requesting_user_role=requesting_user_role)
```

For class based views override `get_form_kwargs`:

```
class MyView(SomeGenericView):
    ...

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        requesting_user_role = # Get it using self.request.user or self.kwargs if something is captured from url
        kwargs.update({'requesting_user_role': requesting_user_role})
        return kwargs
```